# How to add argument to objc functions in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on an application and have run into a problem. I would like to programmatically create a <kbd>UISwitch</kbd> with a function called every time I switch the switch. The problem is that I am going to have a large number of switches (I cannot determine the exact amount since it changes). I want to pass an argument along with the <kbd>#selector</kbd> function.

What I have:

```swift
let onOff = UISwitch()
onOff.frame = CGRect(x: xPos, y: yPos, width: 0, height: 0)
onOff.addTarget(self, action: #selector(filtersViewController.switchStateDidChange(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
onOff.setOn(true, animated: false)

self.view.addSubview(onOff)

// ----------- //

@objc func switchStateDidChange(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    if (sender.isOn == true) {
        print("ON")
    } else {
        print("OFF")
    }
}
```

What I want (in pseudocode):

```
#selector(filtersViewController.switchStateDidChange(_:, )), for: .valueChanged)

@objc func switchStateDidChange(_ sender: UISwitch, identifier: firstSwitch)
```

Please note that this code is in a for loop, hence the <kbd>self</kbd>s.

I get different error message every time I experiment, but the one I get for just trying to add an argument gives:

```
Instance member 'switchStateDidChange' cannot be used on type 'filtersViewController'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?
```

Note: my viewController is called filterViewController.

Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: Whats wrong with just using the `sender` object? If you would like to know which switch is the sender just add an IBOutlet to each UISwitch and just switch the sender to check which one is the sender

Comment: Alternatively you can add a tag to switches which you can be compared for identification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot make Cocoa add an extra parameter to a UIControl target-action message. All of that is set in stone by Cocoa.

However, you have two choices that are very easy.

---

The parameter you do get is the `sender`. As in your code:

```
@objc func switchStateDidChange(_ sender: UISwitch)
```

As your code rightly says, the `sender` *is* the switch. So if you subclass UISwitch to have an `identifier`, or use the `tag` that it already has, you can just immediately ask for that property of the `sender` and now you know what you've got.

---

The other possibility is: don't use target-action! Well, you have to use it, but you can send the message in some other way. For example, I've got a UISwitch subclass that sends the action message to *itself* and then posts a Notification in response. Well, you can include any info you want in a Notification! So that's a flexible way to notify anyone you like that the switch has switched, along with any info you like.

(By the way, the new iOS 13 Combine framework is an even better way to implement this. It's a great replacement for target-action.)

Comment: Cool, looks great, but can you add some code for the identifier part (I'm a newbie at Swift)? Thanks!

Comment: You are the one who proposes an `identifier` in your pseudocode. I have no idea what you have in mind. I'm just telling how to make a UISwitch have one: subclass and give it one.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a parameter to the selector you need a `tag`

```
var switches = [UISwitch]()

(0..<10).forEach {  
   let switch  = ///
   switch.addTarget...
   switch.tag = $0
   .....
   switches.append(switch)
}
```

Comment: switch is a reserved keyword you would need to escape it to use it as a instance variable name